# Why doesn't media query including orientation property work in iframe?

Tags: css, iframe, orientation, media-queries

I have an issue with a media query in an iframe. I figured out that my media queries seem to work as long as I don't specify the orientation.
This media query works just fine:

```
@media
screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px),
screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px),
screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1/1)    and (max-device-width: 1024px),
screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /*Styles here*/
}
```

But when I add the orientation property it doesn't work anymore (neither orientation: portrait nor orientation: landscape):

```
@media
screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1/1)    and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 1)      and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /*Styles here*/
}
```

Similar media queries work just fine in my main CSS, but this issue only appeares in the CSS-file that is used within an iframe. Anyone that has any ideas how to solve this?
Isn't it possible to detect orientation from an iframe CSS? I would really appretiate some help with this!

Looks like there are other people having the same issue but I have not been able to find a solution for the problem.

Edit:
Just to clarify some ambiguities, I have tested the website on several mobile devices, but it's mainly tablets I try to target with this one.

Comment: How can an iFrame change orientation? Would you turn the screen on its side? There might be some way to fake it though.

Comment: Well, I hoped that the side that is displayed inside the iframe also should detect the orientation of the device. But that might not be the case?

Comment: Oh, you're testing the iFrame on a mobile device? I didn't get that from the question :)

Comment: Oh, sorry! Yes, I tested it on multiple mobile devices =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that this is a bad solution but at least it is working and since I got the control of both the main page and the page that is showed in the iframe I can't see that there should be any direct danger. Anyhow, this is my solution:

I had an idea that the problem may be possible to solve with javascript instead of CSS. But I still couldn't get the right orientation even with javascript, so I guess the issue actually originates from that the page inside the iframe doesn't know anything about its parent's environment. However, I discovered that it is possible to call methods from the main page's javascript if the methods are located in a file called parent.js. This makes it possible to create a method that checks the main page's orientation and call this from the iframe's javascript. This solution is of course applicable on any other similar problem. It do, however, require that you got access to both the code for the main page and the page that is loaded in the iframe.

Edit: As muzzamo mentioned in the comments does this solution require that the code for the main page and the code for the iframe are located at the same domain. Sorry for being unclear!
-End of edit-

Code from parent.js:

```
function getDeviceOrientation() {
    var devOri = window.orientation;
    return devOri;
}
```

Code from iframe.js:

```
function changeFontSize() {
    var parentOrientation = parent.getDeviceOrientation();
    //do stuff dependent on value of parentOrientation or whatever
}
```

As already mentioned: I'm not sure that this is a GOOD solution, but at leats it is a solution. Since I'm new to javascript I would still appreciate comments on my solution and/or other (better) solutions to the problem. But I hope this will help others with similar problems!

PS. Don't forget to include the parent.js-file in the HTML-file's head as well!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/parent.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention one thing! When the site is tested in the browser locally I got the error message "unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with url...", but this disappeared when uploading the site to the server. Good luck everyone!

Comment: Using a file called parent.js is unnecessary.

Also, this will only work if the parent IFrame is hosted on the same domain.

Comment: It is? Okey, thx @muzzamo! But how do I call the method from my ordinary script.js-file then? And you are absolutely right regarding the same domain stuff, I was just a little bit unclear in my post earlier!